# Issues trying to add records to an access database through vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to add a record to a table in a Microsoft Access database through Visual Basic.

This is the code I'm using at the moment: (Within a sub)

```
    Dim OleDbConstring As String = My.Settings.CMDataBaseConnectionString & ";"
    Dim Con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(OleDbConstring)
    Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand
    MsgBox("Adding?")
    Cmd.Connection = Con
    Cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, [Password], IsAdmin, TeacherID) VALUES ('" &
        NewUsername.Text & "', '" &
        NewPassword.Text & "', " &
        NewIsAdmin.Checked().ToString & ", " &
        NewTeacher.SelectedValue & ")"
    Con.Open()
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Con.Close()
```

There are no errors thrown and the program doesn't stop at all, I can see the message box so I know the code is being run. However there are no changes made to the database each time. I have checked the field data types and everything is as it should be.

The scenario is a user selects a user, a username (turned into TeacherID), a password, and ticks if they're an admin or not. When they click a button, that code is run.

Also; **I am aware that I should be using parameters to avoid SQL string injection, I am only writing it like this to be sure incorrect parameter coding (etc.) isn't contributing to the problem**

Comment: What value does `ExecuteNonQuery` return?  If it's not zero then the code is working exactly as it should and you're just not looking for the data properly, which is not all that uncommon.  Also, what is your connection string?

Comment: By the way, appending that semicolon to the connection string is pointless and your data adapter also serves no useful purpose.

Comment: My connection string is 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Leo2016MP1.accdb' which has worked for select queries elsewhere in the project. I will check the value of `Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and also check if the data is being stored in the wrong place.

Comment: The data adapter is a leftover from previous code that I commented out and excluded from this, I'll remove it. As for the colon, that's just a habit.

Comment: When posting here, please make sure not to include irrelevant code because it just makes our job harder.

Comment: The data is not being stored in the wrong place.  It's you who's looking for it in the wrong place or, more likely, at the wrong time.  I suggest that you read the following to learn how local data files are managed: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx.  Just note that the word of caution they mention can and probably should be ignored because, if it's not, then you can't retain any data changes between sessions if you make code modifications.

Comment: I found the data, it's in a database in the bin folder. I believe I've set the program to 'copy always' but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Essentially, the new changes are being saved to this database but not to the database in the root folder, which is the one being used to load data from on startup. I will keep playing around but is there any other potential reason?

Comment: You've missed the point.  There are two databases.  The one in the project folder with all the other source files is the source file.  When you build your project, a copy of that source file is created and placed in the output folder and it's that output file that your application connects to.  Your application knows NOTHING about the source file.  If you run your app, save data changes, then make code changes and build again, a new copy of the source file overwrites your changes.  If you use `Copy If Newer` then no copy will be made unless the source file has changed.

Comment: I get it now, so how do I get the changes made to the temporary database be saved to the one in the project folder?

Comment: You don't.  Why would you want to?  The idea is that the source file remains clean so that you don't have to do anything to make it clean when it comes time to deploy.

Comment: I see what you mean, so by that logic this wouldn't be an issue when I do publish it?

Comment: Exactly, which is the whole point.  When you publish, a copy of the clean source file is created in the Release output folder, free of all the garbage accumulated in the copy used while debugging.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it.